# Searching 1000 messages for a string extremely slow

Tags: performance, vba, outlook

I wrote this code that seeks a string in all messages within all mailboxes (average of 100 messages per mailbox (10 mailboxes total)).

The code works but it is too slow, even freezes Outlook.

Is there something I can do to make it faster?

```vb
Sub InboxSeeker(Word As String)

    Dim u As Integer, AddressArr() As String, Users() As String, Element As Variant, Label As Control

    GetOutlook
    AddressArr = QryLoop_Specific("Company", "Address", "Users", "Team", "Samples", "Address")
    
    For Each Element In AddressArr
        Set lFolder = GetFolder(Element)
            Set lItems = GetFolder(Element).Items
            For Each lMsg In lItems
                If InStr(1, lMsg.Body, Word, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, lMsg.Subject, Word, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    DoEvents
                    ReDim Preserve Users(u)
                    Users(u) = QrySingleResult("Company", "FullName", "Users", "Address", Element)
                    u = u + 1
                End If
            Next lMsg
    Next Element
```

Comment: One more thing: I tested the code just checking in all SUBJECTS and it works much better. But I need to check the bodies also, and this part seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure why you need `DoEvents` at each iterations, but you might need it in your GUI, otherwise just do it once at the end.

I believe that ReDim of the array all the time is not very efficient. Why not using a Collection?
[Collections vs Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1ad18x6(v=vs.90).aspx)

You could change your code to include

```
Dim Users as new Collection
...
Users.Add QrySingleResult("Company", "FullName", "Users", "Address", Element)
```

Comment: You are right. It will speed up a little bit, but as I said, the critical part is: 

If InStr(1, lMsg.Body, Word, vbTextCompare) > 0

Answer (score 0):

```
 For Each Element In AddressArr
   Set lFolder = GetFolder(Element)
     Set lItems = GetFolder(Element).Items
     For Each lMsg In lItems
```

Instead of iterating over all folders and items in Outlook you need to use the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods of the Items class to find Outlook items that matches your conditions.

Also I'd suggest using the [AdvancedSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Namespace class which performs a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string.

Answer (score 0):

Use Items.Find/FindNext

```
set item = lItems.Find("@SQL=(""urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription"" LIKE '%something%') OR (""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F"" LIKE '%something%') ")
while Not (item is Nothong)
  ... 
  set Item = lItems.FindNext
wend
```